# send an HTML formatted email using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, html, sdk, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am formatting a mail with HTML content and sending it using MFMailComposeViewController.But on the receiver side mail is not reaching in HTML format.Only Plain text is visible.How could I resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to set the message body using the following lines:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString *emailBody = @"<p><b>Hello World</b></p>";                         
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if you set isHTML param to YES, your message body can be sent as plain/text if the message body can be represented as such.

In my case adding a link in the message body helped. Bold formatting with  tags works too. Tricky!

Tested on iPod 1G 3.1.3.

Comment: This was exactly my issue! Yes, 7 years after this question, MFMailComposeViewController still doesn t respect HTML until you use specific tags. I used `<strong>` and it was ignored, so I changed to `<b>` and it works.